# Checking class of all columns in data.frame

Tags: r

Why `apply` doesn't work?

Look at this:

```
apply(diamonds, 2, class)["carat"]
#      carat 
# "character" 

class(diamonds$carat)
# [1] "numeric"
```

:O

Comment: `apply` activate a `as.matrix` conversion; try with `as.matrix(diamonds)`; each column is of class `char`; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199599/r-apply-function-deactivation-of-matrix-conversion

Comment: yeee but that topic should be named better cuz I didn't find that and I was seeking a wihle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `lapply(diamonds, class)`

Also `apply` still worked , but the result is not right, it will return all type to `character`. look into the [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html)

`apply` works on `arrays/matrices`, not `data.frames`. 
when you using it in `data.frame`  it will convert to `matrix`.

Comment: but why apply doesn't work? I thought `apply( ..., 2, function(x))` run the function through every column, isn't it?

Comment: It is work on my side

Comment: @G5W I added some explain.

Comment: @Wen - that was helpful.  Thanks.